# Free fall - forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws, acceleration, collision

> A question that came into my mind: Given that an object is being released with zero initial velocity in some hight H relatively to an arbitrary surface, it’s falling with an influence of a gravitational force solely.
>   What will be the force (in newtons) that it applies on the surface at the hit moment?

My attempt:
I know how to deal with constant acceleration according to the second law of motion, so I thought that according to this law at the hit moment the forces that apply on the object are its weight and the normal force that the surface applies on him - and he apply on the surface according to the third law of motion, so I have the following property:
$$ \sum F = mg - N = ma$$
 Whereas $a$ is the gravitational acceleration.
I don’t know why but it seems a little unsafe for me to conclude that.

Comment: Does not compute.

Comment: @Qmechanic What do you mean by that? Can’t I find it, that’s no any possible way?

Comment: You need additional information.

Comment: @sammygerbil No, why the hell would I duplicate another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the object and the surface.

Whenever a real object hits another and comes to a complete stop, two things happen from physical perspective:

1. The kinetic energy of the moving object is reduced to 0.
2. A force is acting on the object.

Whenever real objects hit each other, there will be deformation. Consider a bowling ball and a basket ball. If the bowling ball drops on your foot, the kinetic energy is converted on a very short distance because there's not much deformation going on. The basket ball on the other hand can squeeze so the energy will be converted along a longer path. This corresponds to a lesser force because the work $W$ done (the energy converted) can be expressed as $W=Fs$. If $s$ is small, $F$ must be large to get the same work done.

One way to look at the original problem might be the universal $F=ma$ to find the force, but it's hard to get to the actual acceleration. It is large (because the velocity changes abruptly) and points upwards.

Another, maybe simpler way is to look at energies and the fact that the kinetic energy of the object is reduced to zero along a (very short) path.

Since $W = Fs \Rightarrow F = \frac{W}{s}$ and $W = \Delta KE = \Delta PE = mgh$ you can calculate the force if you make assumptions about the distance the object needs to stop.

Comment: So the force depends on the hight it’s falling from or the distance till it stops, didn’t quite get this part tbh

Comment: Both. The higher the fall, the greater the force and the longer the stopping distance (think squishy object/soft surface), the smaller the force.

Comment: This is theory behind pads and helmets: increase stopping distance, decrease peak force.

Answer (score 0):

A body which falls on the ground can undergo elastic or inelastic collision with the ground.

(i) Elastic collision :
 In elastic collisition there is no loss of energy in the process. Therefore the body rebounds with the same velocity (Conserving kinetic energy). Using this property we can deduce that the total change in momentum of ball is

$\Delta p = 2 m v$

By Newton's second law of motion

$ F =  \frac{ \Delta p}{\Delta t}$

Therefore force on the ball is

$ F = \frac{2mv}{t}$

Here, t is the time in which the body rebounds.

By law of conservation of energy,

$ v = \sqrt{2gh} $

$ \therefore F = \frac {2\sqrt{2}m\sqrt{gh}}{t}$

By Newton's third law of motion the force on the body is equal to the force exerted on the ground.

(ii) Inelastic Collision : 
In inelastic collision there is some loss of mechanical energy which goes to deforming the shape of the body. We deduce from this that the velocity with which the body rebounds is less than the velocity with which it strikes. The relation between the velocities is given by a factor

$ e= \frac {velocity\space of  \space separation}{velocity\space  of \space approach} $

$ \therefore Velocity\space after\space collision = ev$

$ \therefore \Delta P = mv(e+1)$

By Newton's second law of motion

$F= \frac {mv(e+1)}{t}$

By law of conservation of energy,

$ v = \sqrt{2gh} $

$ \therefore F = \frac {\sqrt{2}m(e+1)\sqrt{gh}}{t}$

By Newton's third law of motion the force on the body is equal to the force exerted on the ground.

Note that for elastic collision e=1 for which the result still the same.